# Creating a table based upon number of rows/columns entered

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to build a table based upon the answer to 2 questions, with Question 1 "How many risks are in the current process?" to determine the number of columns (i.e. one per risk) and the second question "How many controls in the current process?" determines the number of rows to use (i.e one per control). Is there an easy way to build a table to show a matrix that can then be used for risk/control relationships?

[image]

Comment: So if I understand your question correctly, based on your input in the image, you hoped to generate a table with 4 rows and 5 cols right?

Comment: Not quite - if I had cell A2 and B2 as an input - A2 being number of columns, B2 rows - then I want to automatically create the table as a blank template into which the user will enter the risks across the columns and the controls down the rows.

Answer (score 2):

This was a fun one, so I'll plan to make a [YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/6F8BXqPXG2w) on this later tonight and come back here to post my link. But here's a quick explanation of what I did.

I started by using `A2` cell for # of rows, and the `B2` cell for # of columns. Then I created a button of which I will assign it to a macro, explained in a bit.

Next I created the base layout for the table. This includes:
`D5` to hold "Control ID"
`E5` to hold "Control Description"
`F3` to hold "Risk ID"
`F4` to hold "Risk Description"

Also, let's start by adding the first Control and Risk blocks, as every table would presumably start with at least 1 control and 1 risk. So
`D6` will have "C1"
`E6` will have "Control 1 Description"
`G3` will have "R1"
`G4` will have "Risk 1 Description"

Then to keep consistent with your table, I put a black highlight on cells `F5` and `G5`.

Now we can create the macro, using the following code:

```
Sub CreateTable()
    ' create variable x to hold # of rows from A2
    Dim x As Integer
    x = Range("A2").Value
    ' calculate the row range from x
    Let RowRange = "7:" & 7 + x - 2
    ' copy row 6 into each row in the calculated range
    Rows("6:6").Copy Range(RowRange)
    ' update the text in the newly created rows to match 
    ' the corresponding control number
    For i = 2 To x
        Let ControlIdRow = 5 + i
        Cells(ControlIdRow, 4).Value = "C" & i
        Cells(ControlIdRow, 5).Value = "Control " & i & " Description"
    Next i

    Dim y As Integer
    y = Range("B2").Value
    Columns("G:G").Copy Range(Columns(8), Columns(8 + y - 2))
    For i = 2 To y
        Let RiskIdCol = 6 + i
        Cells(3, RiskIdCol).Value = "R" & i
        Cells(4, RiskIdCol).Value = "Risk " & i & " Description"
    Next i
End Sub
```

Basically what's happening is that we create a variable `x` and assign it to be the number of rows, as input from cell `A2`. Then we use that to calculate the row range starting at row 7 (which will start as Control 2 since Control 1 is on row 6). Then we just copy the entire row 6 up until the specified range. Now (starting at the `For` loop), we need to edit the text in the cells to match the corresponding names (i.e. the second control will be C2, Control 2 Description, the third will be C3, Control 3 Description 3, and so on). Then just essentially repeat that same block, changing the respective values to match the Risks.

Then don't forget to assign the button to the new macro. Now you should be able to enter in a value for rows (`A2`) and a value for columns (`B2`) and click the button, and it should automatically create the table for you.

As mentioned, I'll create a YouTube video later tonight detailing this more and update this answer to point there.

**Update**
I noticed your picture has a checkmark in it, so here's the code to be able to just select a cell and have a green checkmark appear in the cell. Then clicking the cell again will remove the checkmark.

Open up the visual basic editor, and click the `Sheet 1` code from the left. Then apply the following code in there:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If ActiveCell.Row > 5 And ActiveCell.Column > 6 Then
        If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
            Target.Value = ChrW(&H2713)
        Else
            If ActiveCell.Value = ChrW(&H2713) Then
                Target.Value = ""
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

[Link to YouTube Tutorial on this answer](https://youtu.be/6F8BXqPXG2w)

Comment: I look forward to seeing the YouTube tutorial - thank you very much.

Comment: @Richard I updated my answer with the YouTube tutorial. Let me know if that's what you were looking for

Comment: absolutely perfect - thank you very much for all you support. I will also provide comments on both of the YouTube tutorials later today....I only started playing with VBA recently and don't really understand the language yet, but it is so helpful....once again - thank you :)

Comment: glad I can help, learned some cool new things myself! Be sure to mark the question as answered by accepting the answer